# Unity on mobile cuts off sides (not canvas related), on different resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, resolution

I'm developing a 3d game on unity and using the 1080x1920 portrait resolution.

When I build and run the project on my phone, which has a 1080x2340 resolution in portrait, it cuts off part of the game (the sides).

[red lines indicating where it cuts off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZocjX.png)

The camera doesn't follow, so the player can "go out of the screen".

How can I fix this, making sure my game looks the same on different resolutions?

(edited to correct resolution order)

Answer (score 1):

Does your play area have a fixed size? If the in-game play area's aspect ratio isn't the same as the device running the game, you'll have to either cut off part of it or include blank space at the top/bottom or left/right. Unity's camera orthographic size dictates how tall the camera view is, but not how wide. The width is just `screenAspectRatio * camera orthographic size`.

To fix this:

```
float aspect = Screen.Width / Screen.Height;
myCamera.orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(playAreaHeight, playAreaWidth / aspect);
```

This will cause the camera's view to be either too wide or too tall rather than too small.

Comment: That playAreaHeight and playAreaWidth would be the resolution? what values should I put in them?

Comment: playAreaHeight and playAreaWidth seem to be the area covered by the camera, the logical size of the screen.  So, if the camera covers a height of -5 to 5, and a width of -12 to 12, then playAreaHeight is 5, and playAreaWidth is 12.